# Are there more effective or efficient ways to code lengthy texts?

Tags: c++, string, tooltip, c-preprocessor, mingw32

I have an application that will have numerous lengthy tooltips. For example I have code, for just one such tooltip, along the lines of the following:-

```
//Less SSA (ATi-SSA) (as coded in a header)
std::string GetLessSSA_tt() {
    std::string less_ssastr = "Less SSA = The amount after deducting the SSA from the ATI.";
    less_ssastr.append("\n\nAs such reducing the amount used for calculation purposes");
    //etc
    return less_ssastr;
}

 ......

//Coded at various places not within the header
std::string tooltip = GetLessSSA_tt();
```

I believe that a header file is perhaps the most apt place for separation of data and code, and to avoid duplication of data.

I'm open to suggestions of where to place the data (I'd rule out file/database though due to the requirement for more coding and having the data, which would rarely need updating, distant and perhaps prone to misuse e.g. a file could be changed).

The real issue is the actual coding for the storage of the text. There will be quite a considerable amount. The above example is a simplified/minimalist example of one of the smaller texts. There will be at least 27 topics (terms explained), which equates using, the example methodology, to 27 functions, each likely have at least 5 lines of text.

Arrays/deques/structures would all, I guess, increase duplication.

My knowledge of and ability to use pre-processor commands/macros is currently very limited. All my attempts to use '#defines' failed.

I believe, perhaps mistakenly, that pre-processor commands, could limit portability (not really an issue). However, I suspect that perhaps the pre-processor could make for more efficient/effective coding.

**A summary of what I am trying to achieve is**

***"to reduce the `clutter` around the text strings to a minimum. Primarily their definition but also considering subsequent usage."***

Comment: Have you considered reading it from a file of sorts? That would allow the text to change without the program, plus a developer wouldn't need to write it all (your QA department could write the text etc)

Comment: yes, I actually have this for data that changes annually. However, it's not data that would change or if so very rarely and if it were to change it would probably be because coding changes would apply. The text is explanatory terminology, which has remained the same for over 8 years without any hint of it changing. e.g. SSA stands for Self-Support Amount.......

Comment: P.S. The developer dpt is me, the QA dpt is me, etc etc etc. :)

Comment: If this is on Windows, consider storing the text as text resources in the application. That way, it is also much easier to translate your app to a different language, or change a message, should that be necessary one day. Resources can be edited without the need of recompilation. And they don't clutter your source code. I guess other platforms have similar ways of storing texts and images, etc. in an app.

Comment: Then why not only define the functions in header file, and put the implementation in cpp file, which will eliminate the duplicated texts?

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis, yes on windows. I will have a look at resources. However, to-date my limited experience hasn't been that good with them.

Comment: . @Mine The functions are currently in a header file (I'm not sure if they should be in a cpp file, they currently work in a header). Duplication isn't really the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would place it in a single C++ file, should work with simple constants:

*tooltip.h:*

```cpp
namespace Whatever
{
extern std::string const ToolTip1;
extern std::string const ToolTip2;
}
```

*tooltip.cpp:*

```cpp
namespace Whatever
{
std::string const ToolTip1(
        "some lengthy tooltip\n"
        "with several lines"
        );
std::string const ToolTip2(
        "a shorter one"
        );
}
```

If you prefer functions:

*tooltip.h:*

```cpp
namespace Whatever
{
std::string const& toolTip1();
std::string const& toolTip2();
}
```

*tooltip.cpp:*

```cpp
namespace Whatever
{
namespace
{
std::string const ToolTip1(
        "some lengthy tooltip\n"
        "with several lines"
        );
std::string const ToolTip2(
        "a shorter one"
        );
}

std::string const& toolTip1() { return ToolTip1; }
std::string const& toolTip2() { return ToolTip2; }
}
```

I would not place the constants into a header - you at first multiply the constants in the single compilation units, and I feel uncomfortable relying on the linker spotting identical strings...

**Edit:**
Considering MikeT's comments and (rejected) edit:

tooltip.h:

```cpp
namespace Whatever
{
extern char const* const ToolTip1;
extern char const* const ToolTip2;
}
```

tooltip.cpp:

```cpp
namespace Whatever
{
char const* const ToolTip1 = "theToolTip";
char const* const ToolTip2 = "theToolTip";
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
// before:
// addToolTip(getToolTip1().c_str());
// now:
addToolTip(ToolTip1);
```

As long as there is only one single include of the header file globally (into one single source file, and not included within other headers), there won't be a problem moving the definitions from the tooltip.cpp file into the header file and drop the source file. I consider this insecure, though, as this might lead to linker problems as soon as this fact changes. Keeping header and source file separate as I proposed will prevent problems now and in the future.

Additionally, it makes exchanging the language at compile time easy, as we can simply do:

```cpp
gcc main.cpp, something.cpp, tooltip_en-GB.cpp -o theApplication # English translation
gcc main.cpp, something.cpp, tooltip_es-ES.cpp -o theApplication # Spanish translation
# ...
```

Comment: I will certainly have a go at adapting what you posted. I think one of my issues concatenation (didn't like using 'mystring.append("more stuff");' so std::string const mystring("text" "more");' appears to overcome one major **clutter**. Spotting identical strings isn't required, perhaps I shouldn't have mentioned duplication. I only used functions to get around my inability to concatenate, so no need I can just drop the string variable into the tooltip add function.

Comment: @MikeT I interpreded "duplicating" in the sense of "having the same string literal encoded in several different compilation units" anyway - which I assumed you wanted to avoid - for a good reason. This is why I placed the constants into the cpp file and declared them extern in the header...

Comment: just tested an adaptation. I used what you provided in 2nd block (no need for `extern`) just coded `std::string const mystring("text" "more");` in the header file and used `addtooltip(hwnd,ttwnd,(LPTSTR)mystring);`, basically what I was looking for. So marking this as an answer. Just wanted to check first. PS if I'm wrong doing this in header rather than cpp I appreciate knowing why (still very much a newbie to c++ and windows).

Comment: I really like this as now I can separate the paragraphs/sentences with a blank line, which in my opinion a makes it far more readable. So again, thanks.

Comment: Ooops error in above I forgot to include `.c_str()`. So `addtooltip(hwnd,ttwnd,(LPTSTR)mystring);` should be `addtooltip(hwnd,ttwnd,(LPTSTR)mystring.c_str());`

Comment: @MikeT If you do `#include <tooltip.h>`, the file simply is pasted into the source file as is. So you get the constants newly defined in every compilation unit you include the header. Then you are relying on the linker to detect these duplicates. If it does not, you have many different instances of the same constant... This is why I placed it into a separate .cpp file.

Comment: @MikeT Oh, and if you need LPTSTR anyway, which is a simple char (const?)*, then make your constants char const* const, you don't need the wrapping std::string instance then. And you can spare the .c_str().

Comment: How about I give you the code to write :) :) :). Thanks, will do that.

Comment: understand now . I do have `#ifndef CSATERMS_H_INCLUDED`
`#define CSATERMS_H_INCLUDED` and only 1 `#include "csaterms.h"` (only a single core cpp file/compilation unit all other files are headers with the `#ifndef..`. none do/would include this). Is that OK? (Multiple compilation units are beyond me at present).

Comment: @MikeT An include guard won't prevent you from this problem. If you include the header into different cpp files, the guard is not yet defined in any one of them... Include guards protect you from including the same header more than once (directly or indirectly). Imagine you did `#include <a.h> #include <b.h>` and both a.h and b.h included tooltips.h. This is what include guards are for.

Comment: @MikeT If, however, there is only one single source file including the tooltips.h file and no other header is including it (as I interpret your last comment), then you are safe, too.

Comment: just tried  the whole thing i.e. cpp with code setting the constant value, header just with just the define and then main file. Worked first time (really thought I might have problems trying to tell the compiler to compile both sources (I had quite a few getting c++14 instead of c++11)). Anyway will go that way and again thanks for explaining everything and for your patience.